# How to determine if Hazelcast CPSubsystem is enabled?

Tags: hazelcast

Is there any way to validate if Hazelcast's CPSubsystem (introduced in HC 3.12) is enabled by an HC member or client?  If I try to access the CPSubsystem and it isn't enabled, HC will throw an exception.  However, using exceptions for flow control is a bad practice, and I would rather check if it is enabled first prior to accessing it.

I haven't been able to find any mechanism to allow me to query its status without tripping the exception.  Does such a method exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately only way to figure out whether or not CPSubsystem is enabled to check `CPSubsystemConfig.cpMemberCount > 0`. But server configuration is not accessible on client, so this does not work on clients.

PS: I have submitted a new enhancement issue to a new API method: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/15413